# Как приостановить поток?

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность

Как из одного потока приостановить роботу дочернего потока.
Вот у меня есть код:

```
currentThread = new Thread(() => PlayMp3FromUrl(url));
currentThread.IsBackground = true;
currentThread.Start();
```

А потом мне нужно приостановить запущенный поток, с возможностью в будущем снова продолжить его работу. Знаю что текущий поток можно приостановить при помощи

```
Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
```

А про приостановку из одного потока другого потока нашел только устаревшие методы Thread.Suspend и Thread.Resume.

Comment: Что произойдёт если дочерний поток будет приостановлен в момент владения какой-либо блокировкой, а поток, который должен будет его пробудить, запросит данную блокировку?

Comment: если поток владеет блокировкой и его приостановили, то блокировка будет активной. Соотвественно, другие потоки, которым нужна эта блокировка, будут ждать.

Приостанавливать рекомендуется только самого себя. Приостанавливать другой поток не стоит.

Comment: Я знаю про эту проблему. Но в моем случае такого не должно вообще быть.

Comment: Не очень красивый вариант, но простой. Ваш рабочий поток проверяет флаг, указывающий на состояние - работать или "спать". Если "спать", уходит в ожидание на максимально большое приемлемое время (Thread.Sleep). После "пробуждения", проверяет флаг снова. А второй поток манипулирует этим флагом.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для решения данной задачи вы можете воспользоваться [ManualResetEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting Main()");
            Thread t = new Thread(MainThread);
            t.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            StopMainThread();   // You can call this from your button handler.
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Console.WriteLine("Exiting Main()");
        }



        private static void StopMainThread()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Stopping main thread.");
            _stopper.Set();
        }



        private static void MainThread()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting MainThread()");



            for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
            {
                Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ChildThreadMethod));
                thread.Start(i);



                if (_stopper.WaitOne(80, false))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("MainThread() has been told to stop.");
                    break;
                }
            }



            Console.WriteLine("MainThread() is exiting.");
        }



        private static void ChildThreadMethod(object objThreadNumber)
        {
            int threadNumber = (int)objThreadNumber;

            Console.WriteLine("Thread #" + threadNumber + " is starting.");



            for (int i = 1; ; ++i)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Thread #" + threadNumber + " is on iteration " + i);



                if (_stopper.WaitOne(500, false))  // Sleep for 500 ms, but wake up immediately
                {                                  // if _stopper is signalled.
                    break;
                }
            }



            Console.WriteLine("Thread #" + threadNumber + " is exiting.");
        }



        private static  ManualResetEvent _stopper = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    }
}
```